# WireShark Remote Capture failed:NFLOG link-layer type filtering not implemented

Tags: wireshark, packet-capture

I followed [the official documentation](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes#Remote_Capture).

My remote-server is CentOS 7.9, and I have installed the wireshark in it.

I use the below command to open my **local wireshark software** to capture the remote-server's interface packet:

```
ssh root@remote-server-name 'dumpcap -w - -f "not port 22"' | wireshark -k -i -
```

but I get error information:

```
Capturing on 'nflog'
dumpcap: Invalid capture filter "not port 22" for interface nflog!

That string isn't a valid capture filter (NFLOG link-layer type filtering not implemented).
See the User's Guide for a description of the capture filter syntax.
```

and my **local wireshark software** display the error:
[image: k]

---

**EDIT-01**

I use the below command to special the interface:

```
ssh root@remote-server-name -i .ssh/id_rsa 'dumpcap -w - -f "not port 22"' | wireshark -k -i em1
```

but the wireshark says there is no such device:
[image]

in my server there exist the `em1` indeed.

```
[root@att ~]# ip a | grep em1
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet remote-ip/29 brd remote-ip scope global noprefixroute em1
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is explaining what is the cause of not being able to capture:

> Capturing on 'nflog' dumpcap: Invalid capture filter "not port 22" for
> interface nflog!

The dumpcap command that is executed on the remote server does not have an argument `-i <interface>`, this means dumpcap will select the first interface in finds. In this case interface `nflog`.

All capture filters are compiled based on the link layer type of the interface as some filter elements are only available on interfaces of a certain link-layer type.

In this case the capture filter `not port 22` is not a valid capture filter for the link-layer type of interface nflog.

I assume you meant to capture on the ethernet interface of the remote host. You can list the interfaces on the remote host by using the command `dumpcap -D`. Pick the interface you want to capture on and then add the argument `-i <interface>` to your dumpcap command in the remote capture command.

Comment: I special the interface, but wireshark can not find it.

Comment: You need to supply the interface name on the remote server to the dumpcap command and then use `-r - `  in the tshark command to read the packets from the SSH connection.

In short, you will have to use something like:

`ssh root@remote-server-name -i .ssh/id_rsa 'dumpcap -i em1 -w - -f "not port 22"' | wireshark -k -r -`